# Make a thumbnail from a online streaming video

Tags: python, flash, video, youtube, thumbnails

I am trying to see if it is possible to make a thumbnail pic from an online video (videos run in flash) programmatically. Just to elaborate on what I am exactly looking to do:
I have a link to to a video that plays in a browser using adobe flash. I would like to take a screenshot of the video (at any frame would do for now) using any programming language (prefer python). Also I have noticed that when one uploads a video on youtube, it automatically generates a thumbnail. Any pointers as to if this is a viable option and how to go about it?

Thanks

Comment: You could either download the video and create the thumbnail from that, or printscreen the browser. These are very different approaches, and which one to use is up to you

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a programmatic approach. Downloading is currently not an option but a print screen is okay as long as the entire process from running the video and taking a screen shot is done programatically.

Comment: You can do any of these options programatically. If you want to go down the second route, for browser automation, there's [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292817/how-to-automate-browsing-using-python). For screenshots, [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846947/get-screenshot-on-windows-with-python). I'm assuming you're on windows.