# How to check for webpages' popups?

Tags: python, firefox, popup, mechanize, html

Is there a possibility if I code a program in python that allows to [automatically browse a given website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292817/how-to-automate-browsing-using-python) using [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to detect if there are popup windows (suggesting advertisements or downloading actions ...) using Python ?. I would appreciate any hint (for example, if you give me a library that fulfills this task I would be very happy)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mechanize cannot handle javascript and popup windows:

- [How do I use Mechanize to process JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802225/how-do-i-use-mechanize-to-process-javascript)
- [Mechanize and Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5793414/mechanize-and-javascript)

To accomplish the goal, you need to utilize a real browser, [headless](http://www.realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/#.U57mRo1dUi4) or not. This is where [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) would help. It has a [built-in support for popup dialogs](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/navigating.html#popup-dialogs):

> Selenium WebDriver has built-in support for handling popup dialog
>   boxes. After you’ve triggerd and action that would open a popup, you
>   can access the alert with the following:
>
> `alert = driver.switch_to_alert()`

Example (using this [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ebkXh/show/)):

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://fiddle.jshell.net/ebkXh/show/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')

# dismiss
button.click()
driver.switch_to.alert.dismiss()

# accept
button.click()
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

See also:

- [Handle Popup Windows](http://learning-selenium-webdriver.blogspot.com/2013/01/handle-popup-windows.html)
- [Click the javascript popup through webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631500/click-the-javascript-popup-through-webdriver)

Comment: Is selenium API able to close the pop up when switching to it ? My aim is to detect popups on a given webpage and close them automatically.

Comment: @begueradj yes, you can `switch_to_alert()` and `accept()` or `dismiss()` it, see this thread for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631500/click-the-javascript-popup-through-webdriver.

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Simple and efficient. Thank you. I want to award you the 100 points but it says I must wait 22 hours to be able to do it.

Comment: @begueradj glad it helped. I'm going to provide you with an example also.

Comment: I did not downvote !!! I tested your code and it works perfectly !!! It is not me, why should I do while your answer is exactly what I have been looking for almost 2 weeks ??

Comment: @begueradj nono, it is not about you. I just cannot understand the reason for downvoting. Since there is no explanation, there is probably a personal reason. Since only the question and my answer received downvotes, I suspect it is coming from another answerer. Though, it is what it is, just glad you solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: One last question if I may, do you think it is possible to browse all the pages of a given website using selenium ?

Comment: @begueradj sure, well, you can recursively extract the links and follow them. Also, you can combine selenium with [`Scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/).. But, it is really a part of a completely different topic..you can even ask it here on SO.

Comment: I did a big mistake :: I awarded the 100 points to the answerer below :( I am so sorry, my connexion is so bad, i got frustrated and i clicked on the wrong place :(

Comment: @begueradj don't worry, that's ok :)

Comment: It is not ok for me, I have faced this problem since 2 weeks, so I feel shame i did this mistake now that you are the only one to help me :(. I asked a question about my mistake on here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260795/how-to-take-back-my-bounty-and-give-it-to-the-right-answerer

Comment: I will follow the answer of this man once I am I able to do that (i must have at least 150 points). I keep you in mind because your answer is more than useful for me (i need it in a big project). It is just a question of being fair with you. Regards. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260795/how-to-take-back-my-bounty-and-give-it-to-the-right-answerer

Comment: @begueradj you have already did a lot of things other people would not do, you showed your concern - this is really enough for me and I appreciate it. You are a good questioner and you deserve the points you have. Besides, it is not about points for me, it is about helping people and solving interesting problems; points and badges are just  bonuses. Thank you, and don't worry about the bounty.

Comment: I did not want to bother you with my question again, but I asked early this morning this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257802/how-to-browse-a-whole-website-using-selenium) but I did not get any answer. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, **Mechanize**'s browser seems to skip the pop-ups so the title, URL, and HTML are identical for both pop-ups and normal pages.

Frankly, `Python` is not the right tool for this job and is lagging behind in this respect IMHO. Having spent months doing web crawling, for sites that use `Javascript` extensively (the number of which is greatly increasing nowadays), I find that using `Javascript-Based` environments like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [SlimerJS](http://slimerjs.org/) are simply better for what you're trying to do.

If you have the luxury to use `Javascript-Based` environments, I'd say go right ahead. However, you can still use python. [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/) embeds [`Ghost Driver`](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver). You can use [Ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) to utilize the power of [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/). Or you can use [`Selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) with `Python` as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631500/click-the-javascript-popup-through-webdriver).

Comment: Thank you for all the links. I have been browsing (quickly) around PhantomJS to see if deals with popups, but I don't find for the moment. Whatever the third party technology I use, it must interact with Python because my main program is done in Python.

Comment: You can check `Ghost.py` at the end of my answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw all the links you gave me, now I am just looking for the possibilities of PhantomJS to discover popup windows, then I can call from a Python program

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11325) might give you a taste.