# get csv data from a website

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

How do I download and read the CSV data on [this](http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/csv/1.0/hour) website using Python:

http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/csv/1.0/hour

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419260/grabbing-text-from-a-webpage

Comment: Isn't it simple CSV?  What have you tried?

Comment: read about the [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2#urllib2) module for downloading the page and the [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for parsing the data.

Comment: Since you're on Python 3.x, make that the [urllib.request](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) module and the [csv](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the data. If you simply want to download the data you can use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html).

```
import urllib2

downloaded_data  = urllib2.urlopen('http://...')

for line in downloaded_data.readlines():
    print line
```

If you need to parse the [csv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) you can use the [urrlib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) and [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) modules.

**Python 2.X**

```
import csv
import urllib2

downloaded_data  = urllib2.urlopen('http://...')
csv_data = csv.reader(downloaded_data)

for row in csv_data:
    print row
```

**Python 3.X**

```
import csv
import urllib.request

downloaded_data  = urllib.request.urlopen('http://...')
csv_data = csv.reader(downloaded_data)

for row in csv_data:
    print(row)
```

Comment: since you're coding it for the OP, add the csv parsing too :)

Comment: Hah. I am in a helpful mood, already on it. :p

Comment: and you should really use urllib2 ;)  -- and I know the feeling, I can't help myself either sometimes...

Comment: I get an error saying that urllib2 doesn't exist as a module which is really strange

Comment: Hah. Yea, bad tendancy when writting code directly in my browser. :p

Comment: ...and parse the date then bring it up on google maps?! Actually, that would be kinda cool.

Comment: @user2117875 Try replacing `urllib2` with `urllib`, but I would recommend that you install the `urllib2` library, but that is a different topic.

Comment: that's exactly the plan @tdelaney. As I said urlib2 is giving me trouble for some reason i get an import error

Comment: i get Attribute error: says the is no attribute urlopen

Comment: I suspect the problem is that the OP is on Python 3, not that he's on Python 1. So just replacing `urllib2` with `urllib` will not solve the problem. You need to use the new renamed version in `urllib.request`.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969726/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-urlopen and then make sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: @user2117875: Meanwhile, if you had followed the link to `urllib2`, or searched for the docs yourself, you would have seen the big note at the top saying "The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named urllib.request and urllib.error" and figured this out, rather than making Fuji guess at your problem.

Comment: Yep, like @abarnert said. Make sure to read the http://stackoverflow.com/about and http://stackoverflow.com/faq pages. And no worries.

Comment: it reads in the data ok from the website but it has issues with this line: for row in csv_data:. The error is 'the iterator should return strings not bytes', i've tried it with DictReader too, it gives the same error

Comment: try replacing `print row` with `print(', '.join(row))`