# Downloading a web page and all of its resource files in Python

Tags: python, urllib2, wget

I want to be able to download a page and all of its associated resources (images, style sheets, script files, etc) using Python.  I am (somewhat) familiar with urllib2 and know how to download individual urls, but before I go and start hacking at BeautifulSoup + urllib2 I wanted to be sure that there wasn't already a Python equivalent to "wget --page-requisites http://www.google.com".

Specifically I am interested in gathering statistical information about how long it takes to download an entire web page, including all resources.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419235/anyone-know-of-a-good-python-based-web-crawler-that-i-could-use

Answer (score 3):

Websucker?  See http://effbot.org/zone/websucker.htm

Answer (score 2):

websucker.py doesn't import css links. HTTrack.com is not python, it's C/C++, but it's a good, maintained, utility for downloading a website for offline browsing.

http://www.mail-archive.com/python-bugs-list@python.org/msg13523.html
[issue1124] Webchecker not parsing css "@import url"

Guido> This is essentially unsupported and unmaintaned example code.  Feel free
to submit a patch though!