# Python - urlretrieve for entire web page

Tags: python, urllib

with `urllib.urlretrieve('http://page.com', 'page.html')` I can save the index page and only the index of page.com. Does urlretrieve handle something similar to wget -r that let's me download the entire web page structure with all related html files of page.com?

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent of wget in Python to download website and resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221022/equivalent-of-wget-in-python-to-download-website-and-resources)

Comment: Not by itself - to do that, you need to parse the HTML and look for links ([wget docs](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Recursive-Download)). `urllib` doesn't include any HTML parser, but you can use something like lxml.html.

Comment: why can't you use wget or curl?

Comment: Thank you. I could use wget but was looking for a pure Python solution. I may look for the links and parse all the pages then. Regards

Comment: What you want is essentially a simple crawler. Checkout [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Not directly.

If you want to spider over an entire site, look at mechanize: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

This will let you load a page and follow links from it

Something like:

```
import mechanize
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('http://stackoverflow.com')
for link in br.links():
    print(link)
    response = br.follow_link(link)
    html = response.read()
    #save your downloaded page
    br.back()
```

As it stands, this will only get you the pages one link away from your starting point. You could easily adapt it to cover an entire site, though.

If you really just want to mirror an entire site, use wget. Doing this in python is only worthwhile if you need to do some kind of clever processing (handling javascript, selectively following links, etc)