# Web Scrape multiple directories of text files from web site

Tags: python, web, download, screen-scraping, text-files

I have a need to Down load several 1000 individual text files from a Climate repository.
Each Weather Station has a directory, where simple ascii text files are stored, one for each day since the station has been recording...

Is there a way to write a script to down load all files from the diretory?

http://www.sidpabb.org/data/clima/raw/BeiraInam/

Regards

Comment: Yes, there is a way. One way is using urllib2 and beautifulsoup. What did you have in mind and what did you try?

Comment: Probably it will be helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221022/equivalent-of-wget-in-python-to-download-website-and-resources

Comment: I am not at all sure, where to begin with coding this...(Novice) will look at the link thanks

Comment: The other complication is that I need a user name & Password to get access... (which I have) but how is that used in a script?

Comment: Here is a typical file name: BeiraInam_BeiraInam_2012.4.21.dat, there is a file for each day....

Comment: bit late to the party here, but use the awesome [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library for this. You should be able to specify username/password parameters pretty easily with this as well.