# Using wget via Python

Tags: python, linux

How would I download files (video) with Python using wget and save them locally? There will be a bunch of files, so how do I know that one file is downloaded so as to automatically start downloding another one?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you do it?  First search for all the previous questions exactly like yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wget+python.  Second, read this specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419235/anyone-know-of-a-good-python-based-web-crawler-that-i-could-use

Answer (score 22):

Short answer (simplified). To get one file

```
 import urllib.request
 urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://google.com/index.html", filename="local/index.html")
```

You can figure out how to loop that if necessary.

Comment: By now, it seems to be `urllib.request.urlretrieve("...")` if anybody still needs this :)

Comment: @ChrisStenkamp  Looks like there was a full cycle of (python 2's urllib) -> (python 2's urllib2) -> (python 3's urllib).
which means the answer at the moment is for python 2 and your note is to have it work on python 3.

Comment: Could it show progress as well?

Answer (score 21):

Don't do this. Use either [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [`urlgrabber`](http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/) instead.

Comment: This answer needs to be expanded. Why shouldn't `wget` be used?

Comment: Because it starts a whole new process just to do things that Python itself is capable of.

Comment: Because it undermines portability.

Comment: Is it nontrivial to write `wget -rl1 -I /stuff/i/want/ http://url/<incrementing number>` with either of these libs?

Comment: wget works through a VPN client, whereas urllib gives me this error for a https: urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required

Answer (score 15):

If you use [`os.system()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) to spawn a process for the `wget`, it will block until `wget` finishes the download (or quits with an error).  So, just call `os.system('wget blah')` in a loop until you've downloaded all of your files.

Alternatively, you can use [`urllib2`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) or [`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html).  You'll have to write a non-trivial amount code, but you'll get better performance, since you can reuse a single HTTP connection to download many files, as opposed to opening a new connection for each file.

Comment: Isn't it `os.system()` is not recommended to be used and as alternative we should use `subprocess`?

Answer (score 9):

No reason to use os.system.  Avoid writing a shell script in Python and go with something like urllib.urlretrieve or an equivalent.

Edit... to answer the second part of your question, you can set up a thread pool using the standard library Queue class.  Since you're doing a lot of downloading, the GIL shouldn't be a problem.  Generate a list of the URLs you wish to download and feed them to your work queue. It will handle pushing requests to worker threads.

I'm waiting for a database update to complete, so I put this together real quick.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import threading
import urllib
from Queue import Queue
import logging

class Downloader(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(Downloader, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            download_url, save_as = queue.get()
            # sentinal
            if not download_url:
                return
            try:
                urllib.urlretrieve(download_url, filename=save_as)
            except Exception, e:
                logging.warn("error downloading %s: %s" % (download_url, e))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    queue = Queue()
    threads = []
    for i in xrange(5):
        threads.append(Downloader(queue))
        threads[-1].start()

    for line in sys.stdin:
        url = line.strip()
        filename = url.split('/')[-1]
        print "Download %s as %s" % (url, filename)
        queue.put((url, filename))

    # if we get here, stdin has gotten the ^D
    print "Finishing current downloads"
    for i in xrange(5):
        queue.put((None, None))
```

Comment: there is a mistake in `download_url, save_as = queue.get()`. should be `download_url, save_as = self.queue.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

Install wget via pypi http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget/0.3

```
pip install wget
```

then run, just as documented

```
python -m wget <url>
```

Comment: For anyone else who found this confusing, the linked library doesn't use wget. It uses urllib. And it currently doesn't support anything close to what wget ( http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/ ) does.

Answer (score -7):

No reason to use python. Avoid writing a shell script in Python and go with something like bash or an equivalent.

Comment: Writing a shell script in Python is OK. If you want to get something done quickly but you hate the syntax of bash, just do it in Python. If you make a larger project, then yes, try to avoid these external calls.

Comment: Python is a fine scripting language.