# OpenStack Glance: How to download image with wget

Tags: wget

I have setup Glance serverice, and added couple of images for test purposes.

I am able to download the image glance_server/v1/image/ but when I try the same with wget tool from the command line, wget seems not to understand the OVF stream header which is sent before the image.

Has any body came across this and found a way around. Thanks.

Comment: Found this very useful. It solved my problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467609/using-wget-via-python

Comment: @OmerKhalid. You could (a) post that link as an answer to this question, then accept that answer, (b) flag this question for closure as a duplicate of that, or (c) both.