# Error closing wget subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, wget

I am downloading a file using wget in Python using the code below:

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['wget',
                       '-P', 
                       'path/to/folder','http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/wgs/?download=ACHI01.1.fsa_nt.gz'],
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

p1.studout.close()
```

The file gets downloaded and saved correctly in the given folder but the process keeps running. I tried `p1.kills()` but that doesn't work either. 
Please advise.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `p1.terminate()`?

Comment: Because you use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, you have to read stdout by `p1.communicate()`.

Comment: As an aside there's a third party wget module https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget or use urllib2 (see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346872/python-equivalent-of-a-given-wget-command).  Philosophically, I think, wrapping linux cmds is not really the pythonic way of doing things (usually the "best" way is to call the underlying c libs directly using a third party python module someone else wrote for you).  (no idea if this is what the wget python module does though).

Comment: Also this http://urlgrabber.baseurl.org/ suggested in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467609/using-wget-via-python

Comment: have you tried `urllib.urlretrieve()` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use subprocess.call

```
import subprocess 

subprocess.call (['wget', '-P', '/', 'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/wgs/?download=ACHI01.1.fsa_nt.gz'])
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick replies. using subprocess.call worked great !!

Comment: @user1777629: don't use `stdout=PIPE` with `subprocess.call()` function; it may hang the child process if it generates enough output to fill the OS pipe buffer.

Answer (score 0):

A call to `wait()` is missing after the `Popen`, to make the main process wait till the child process is terminated.. The following code seems to work fine:

```
import subprocess as sp

def main(args):
p1 = sp.Popen(['wget', '-P path',
               'http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Traces/wgs/?download=ACHI01.1.fsa_nt.gz'],
               stdout = sp.PIPE)
p1.wait()
return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

(You can also group commandline parameters with their values, if they have any).

Comment: don't use `stdout=PIPE` unless you read from the pipe; it may block the subprocess. For example, try to run `python -c "print(chr(97)*10**2)"` as a subprocess. It should work as is with `10**2` characters. Change it to `10**5` or `10**6`, to see that it blocks forever. Replace `p1.wait()` with `output = p1.communicate()[0]`, to see that it does not block forever if the pipe is consumed. [To discard output, use `DEVNULL` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270665/4279)

Comment: Hi @J.F.Sebastian, thanks for your suggestion. I changed the code to not use stdout and I am just using subprocess.call.